# Cython Extension Type inheriting from int cause a MemoryError

Tags: python, inheritance, crash, cython

I am trying to make an extension type inheriting from int or cython.int. This is necessary for me as I need to be able to use this type as an index for some lists/arrays.

Here is the code to reproduce the bug on Python 2.7.9 Win32 (I'm running Windows 7) with Cython v0.22 on Anaconda:

```
import cython
cimport cython


import sys


cdef class ExtendedInt(int):


    #cdef object __weakref__ # explicitly enable weakref for this extension type, will self-destruct when it is no longer strongly referenced.


    def __add__(a, b):
        return a+b


# Simple test case
def main():
    total_it = 1000
    for i in xrange(total_it):
        for j in xrange(10000000):
            ExtendedInt(j)
        sys.stdout.write("\rGenerating lists of ExtendedInt : %i/%i" % (i, total_it))
```

What happens is that if you try to create lots of ExtendedInt, at some moment the Python interpreter will crash with a MemoryError. With the code snippet above, on my machine with 4 GB memory it crashes at the 11th iteration, but this will vary depending on the machine specs. I tried to enable weakref but it doesn't fix the issue.

However, if you replace the "cdef class ExtendedInt(int):" by just "class ExtendedInt(int)" (so it's no longer an extension type but a simple Python class), then the issue does not happen, there's no MemoryError crash.

Thus it seems that extension types inheriting from integers are not freed correctly, even if I enable the **weakref**. Is this a bug I should fill on the tracker or am I missing something?

Is this a bug of the current Cython version? I could not find any reference on the bugtracker... Or I am missing something that could fix the issue?

Comment: have you tried `cdef class ExtendedInt(cython.int):` instead? you mentioned it but in your example it seems you are getting the Python `int`...

Comment: Yes I tried, and it doesn't work better. Anyway, I confirmed this was a bug with current Cython thank's to the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stefan Behnel discovered that the bug is in Python 2.7 inside intobject.c](https://www.mail-archive.com/cython-devel@python.org/msg04417.html):

> Your extension type automatically inherits the "int_free" slot
>   function from its base type, so the "else" case in "int_dealloc()"
>   will in fact call "int_free()" and append the object to the free list
>   despite *not* being exactly of type PyInt. Then, when creating a new
>   ExtendedInt instance, Python's int-subtype instantiation code
>   *ignores* the free list and instead creates a completely new object.
>
> Thus, the free list keeps growing until it fills all memory and the
>   process dies. I created a CPython ticket.

Here's the [link to the CPython ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue24469).

Here's the answer from Guido Van Rossum:

> The intended solution is to require that int subclasses override
>   tp_free.
>
> Note that much of this code is written pretty much assuming that
>   subclasses are created using class statements (in a regular Python
>   module, not Cython) which take care of all these details. That doesn't
>   mean Cython is wrong to try this, but it does mean there isn't a lot
>   of documentation, and it also means I don't think the thing you
>   reported qualifies as a bug in CPython.

So I'm not sure if this will get fixed or not or if Cython will implement a workaround. Anyway, for those facing the same issue as I did, you can workaround this problem by inheriting from object and then just reimplement the magic methods for integers, like **int**, **index**, **add**, etc as I explained with [a concrete example here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/WJ5BJ5moAh4).